# Проблема с PJAX в Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, pjax

Есть activeform форма, её я заключил между Pjax, и все вроде работает без перезагрузки страницы, но хлебные крошки при переходе по ссылкам не меняются. Методом тыка я так понял что причина в том что инициализация хлебных крошек происходит в шаблоне, и соответственно вот этот кусок кода

```
                    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
                    'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
                    'homeLink'=>isset($this->params['home']) ? $this->params['home'] : ['label'=>'Главная','url'=>'/admin']
                ]) ?>
```

не находится между Pjax и соответственно не обновляется...
попытался в js сделать reload блока breadcrumbs, но тогда перезагружается вся страница.. Есть какие то предложения обновлять хлебные крошки через Pjax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам придется делать это обычным ajax. Логика может такая: при обновлении формы следом запускаете ajax запрос на сервер. Сервер пусть обновит вам крошки. При успешном ответе ajax обновляете ваши крошки ответом с сервера. Для этого сделайте отдельный метод в контроллере, который будет принимать ajax запрос и отдельный view с крошками. Его контроллер будет рендерить и это и будет ответом сервера. Остается только вам положит его в нужный контейнер. Для этого можете обернуть крошки в див и назначить ему понятный id.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

можно запустить скрипт перезагрузки другого Pjax при срабатывании первого

```
$this->registerJs(
    '$("document").ready(function(){
            $("#new_img").on("pjax:success", function() {
           твой код
});
 });'
);
```